# TTMessageController keyboard appears late

Tags: iphone, three20

I have subclassed TTMessageController and remove the _fields and _fieldViews, so basically it has just the textEditor in it, and i wanted the textEditor to become the First Responder so that the keyboard will appear, but still i cant make it work.. It only appear when I started typing from the keyboard (using Simulator not the iPhone's keyboard)...

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think it will work: Override `-[viewWillAppear:]`, and call `super` and then call `[_textEditor becomeFirstResponder]` to set focus to the textEditor:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_textEditor becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

The reason you need to do this is that in a normal `TTMessageController`, `-[TTMessageController viewWillAppear:]` sets keyboard focus to one of the fields, but in your case there are no fields, and you want to instead set focus to the text editor.

Comment: the keyboard still shows up after i input from keyboard, though i got your point.. thanks